# Using .NET Standard from .NET Framework web application fails with "Could not load file or assembly..."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I am trying to use .NET Standard libraries in .NET Framework ASP.NET web applications, and I frequently encounter errors relating to type loading. I have reproduced the problem as follows:

https://github.com/sgarshol/VTSample

I have built a bare-bones `.NET Standard 2.0`  library with a single class:

```
namespace VTLib
{
    public class VTMaker
    {
        public (int, string) GetVT()
        {
            return (3, "value");
        }
    }
}
```

I have referenced this library as a project reference in a console application and a `ASP.NET MVC` application, both `.NET Framework v4.6.2`. Both projects instantiate the class and call `GetVT()`.

The console application works fine.

The web application does not, and I receive the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Checking my the web application/bin folder, I find that the following `.dlls`:

/bin/System.ValueTuple.dll (4.0.2.0, msil, .Net Framework v4.0)
/bin/roslyn/System.ValueTuple.dll (4.0.1.0, msil, .Net Framework v.4.6.2)

Using JetBrains dotPeek, I examine my web application `.dll` and my library `.dll` and glean the following:

- The web application .dll references System.ValueTuple (4.0.2.0), though the .csproj file includes no such reference.
- The library .dll references netstandard (2.0.0.0) as its single reference.

I find that I can "resolve" the issue by manually adding an assembly redirect instruction in the Web.config file:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Have you used Nuget Package Manager to bring System.ValueTuple into your project?

Comment: @IrishChieftain Adding System.ValueTuple to the web application references does not have any appreciable effect on the problem: The relevant .dlls output to the /bin folders remain the same; the error persists.

Comment: Reason I asked was because I saw no mention of it in the packages file, so I thought it might be worth a try doing this explicitly ;-)

Comment: @irishchieftain I avoided adding the package to keep the project to a minimum: it builds fine without it. But I did do a test with the package included (no dice!) at your suggestion, so your input is appreciated :)

Comment: We've had something very similar just now at work. I think there is a bug with the automatic binding redirect generation by .net framework 46x projects referencing .net standard libraries which fail to resolve the dependencies properly. For reference, 4.0.2 = nuget 4.4 and 4.0.3 = nuget 4.5. Why this happens is because you are using a C# 7.0 feature which only exists in .net framework 4.7+, so in order to use it in .net 462 you need to pull in an extra dll. I believe this is why it gets confused and doesnt go through the normal nuget dependency resolution process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the reference to your ASP.NET web project as well.
Transitive references are not supported in this kind of project as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46234330/9595496).

Make sure that all dependencies from referenced packages are also added as reference to your `ASP.NET MVC application`, including `System.ValueTuple`